# Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder KafkaTransactionManager results in a cycle in application context

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I am setting up a basic Spring Cloud Stream producer with Kafka.  The intent is to accept a HTTP POST, save the result of the post to a database with Spring Data JPA, and write the results to a Kafka topic using Spring Cloud Stream Kafka Binder.  I am following the latest binder [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/docs/3.1.3/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka.html#kafka-transactional-binder) on how to setup a KafkaTransactionManager, but this code results in an error on Application startup.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

┌─────┐
|  kafkaTransactionManager defined in com.example.tx.Application
↑     ↓
|  org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration
└─────┘
```

I have the following Bean defined in my Application class, which is the same as documentation.

```
@Bean
public KafkaTransactionManager kafkaTransactionManager(BinderFactory binders) {

    ProducerFactory<byte[], byte[]> pf = ((KafkaMessageChannelBinder) binders.getBinder(null, MessageChannel.class)).getTransactionalProducerFactory();
    KafkaTransactionManager tm = new KafkaTransactionManager<>(pf);
    tm.setTransactionIdPrefix("tx-test");
    return tm;
}
```

It seems that calling `getBinder` causes Spring to create the context again.  How can I resolve this circular dependency?

Dependencies: Spring Boot parent 2.4.6; Spring Cloud BOM 2020.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something must have changed in one of the layers; here is a work around:

```java
@Bean
SmartInitializingSingleton ktmProvider(BinderFactory binders, GenericApplicationContext context) {
    return () -> {
        context.registerBean("kafkaTransactionManager", KafkaTransactionManager.class,
                ((KafkaMessageChannelBinder) binders.getBinder(null, MessageChannel.class))
                        .getTransactionalProducerFactory());
        context.getBean(KafkaTransactionManager.class).setTransactionIdPrefix("tx-test");
    };
}
```

i.e. wait for the other beans to be created before registering and configuring the tm.